# Why Won't My Hidden Field Populate from JavaScript Function?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a JavaScript function that creates a string that I need to use in another form on the website I'm working on. To do this I thought I would just write the value to a hidden field, and then submit it in the HTML form. However, nothing I do will get the value to appear in the field even though the alert will populate.

```
function customFunc(){
    var customD = document.querySelector('input[name = "customD"]:checked').value;
    var customL = document.getElementById('Custom_Length').value; 
    var customW = document.getElementById('Custom_Width').value;  
    var lowerV = customL * customW;
    var maxV1 = Math.ceil(lowerV/100)*100;
    var maxV2 = maxV1 - 1;
    var lowerB = maxV1 - 100;
    var pStyle = document.querySelector('input[name = "pl"]:checked').value;
    var itemTest = pStyle +customD+"."+lowerB+"-"+maxV2;
    alert(itemTest );
    return itemTest ;
    document.getElementById('testSku').value = itemTest ;
}
```

On the HTML side I have this as the hidden field

```html
<input type="text" name="testSku" id="testSku">
```

Comment: Read about [__`return`__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) keyword in JavaScript or any programming language...

Comment: The function stops running when it executes `return itemTest`. Anything after that is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` statement ends a function and returns to the caller. Anything after that in the function is not executed. So the assignment to the input's value is ignored. Put the `return` statement last.

```
function customFunc(){
    var customD = document.querySelector('input[name = "customD"]:checked').value;
    var customL = document.getElementById('Custom_Length').value; 
    var customW = document.getElementById('Custom_Width').value;  
    var lowerV = customL * customW;
    var maxV1 = Math.ceil(lowerV/100)*100;
    var maxV2 = maxV1 - 1;
    var lowerB = maxV1 - 100;
    var pStyle = document.querySelector('input[name = "pl"]:checked').value;
    var itemTest = pStyle +customD+"."+lowerB+"-"+maxV2;
    alert(itemTest );
    document.getElementById('testSku').value = itemTest ;
    return itemTest ;
}
```